# Accessing Hash of Hash of Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, hash

I'm attempting to grab event log entries which are passed in xlm, convert them into a hash and then store into a database.

I'm currently using the XmlSimple gem to convert the xml input into a hash.

Test sample input:

```
require 'xmlsimple'

h = XmlSimple.xml_in('
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
  </System>
</Event>
', { 'KeyAttr' => 'name' })


puts "#{h}"
```

This returns:

```
{"xmlns"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event", "System"=>[{"Provider"=>[{"Name"=>"Service Control Manager", "Guid"=>"{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}", "EventSourceName"=>"Service Control Manager"}]}]}
```

How can I access the System Provider GUID?

I can return all of the System elements by doing:

```
puts "#{h['System']}"
```

However

```
puts "#{h['System']['Provider'}"
```

Returns:

```
can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
```

I've tried casting the result to a string with no luck. Do I have the XmlSimple formatting wrong? Am I accessing the wrong key? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` at the beginning of the `"System"` denotes that its value is an array of hashes. You can do this:

```
puts "#{h['System'][0]['Provider'}"
```

at the same time `"Provider"` itself is an array, so you would have to do the same for it, for instance:

```
puts "#{h['System'][0]['Provider'][0]['Guid']"
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't event notice that! puts "#{h['System'][0]['Provider'][0]['Guid']}" Gives me to GUID value I was after.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just missing a closing `]`. Hashes should nest arbitrarily deep without problem.

Answer (score 1):

`h['System']` is an Array.
Use:

```
h['System'][0]['Provider']
```

Answer (score 1):

be careful of the arrays

```
h["System"].first["Provider"].first["Guid"]
```